# Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<RouteComponentProps<{}>>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am new to reactjs, i have tried some solutions but it is not working in my project.

i am trying to call other component from inside of another one, but its showing error.

component is being called from another:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
import Griddle, { plugins } from 'griddle-react';


interface State {
    name?: string;
    ItemNo?: string;
    StockCode?: string;
    Description?: string;
    Quantity?: string;
    Tag?: string;
    PurchaseDescription?: string;
    Remark?: string;
    ddlQty?: string;
    ddlHazardClass?: string;
    ddlHazardMaterial?: string;

}
interface MyObj {
    shnh_approval_date: string
    shnh_approval_date_formatted: string
    po_number: string
}
export class LineitemDetailsComponent extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>> {
    public state: State;
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { name: "" };
    }

    public render() {
        return (<div>

        </div>)
    }

}
```

main component who is calling another component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
import Griddle, { plugins } from 'griddle-react';
import axios from 'axios'
import { LineitemListComponent } from '../components/LineitemListComponent';
import { LineitemDetailsComponent } from '../components/LineitemDetailsComponent';

interface State {
    name?: string;
    ddlPrefix?: string;
    ddlShipFrom?: string;
    ddlShipTo?: string;
    ddlNoticeType?: string;
    ddlStatus?: string;
    txtDesc?: string;
    isHovered?: boolean;
}


export class LineComponent extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>> {
    public state: State;
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { name: "", ddlPrefix: "All", ddlShipFrom: "All", ddlShipTo: "All", ddlNoticeType: "All", ddlStatus: "All", txtDesc: "", isHovered: false  };

    }



    public render() {
        return (<div>           

                <div>
                    <LineitemDetailsComponent  />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

route.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Layout } from './components/Layout';
import { Home } from './components/Home';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/HeaderComponent';
import { LineitemListComponent } from './components/LineitemListComponent';
import { LineitemDetailsComponent } from './components/LineitemDetailsComponent';
import { LineComponent } from './components/LineComponent';




export const routes = <Layout>
    <Route exact path='/' component={ Home } />
    <Route path='/HeaderComponent' component={HeaderComponent} />
    <Route path='/LineitemListComponent' component={LineitemListComponent} />
    <Route path='/LineitemDetailsComponent' component={LineitemDetailsComponent} />
    <Route path='/LineComponent' component={LineComponent} />

</Layout>;
```

after removing the RouteComponentProps<{}>, router throws error.
i am really not aware what to do here.